# Best way to convert Enum to Set in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following enum:

```
enum Animes {
    OnePiece = 'One Piece',
    Naruto = 'Naruto',
    Bleach = 'Bleach'
}
```

What is the best way to convert this enum to a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)?

Comment: There's always `new Set([Animes.OnePiece, Animes.Naruto, Animes.Bleach])`

Comment: You could also loop through the enum and just add the values to  your set?

Comment: Hey @SterlingArcher, that question/answer is for javascript. Javascript doesn't provide enums out of the box. My question is for typescript. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, there's

```
new Set([Animes.OnePiece, Animes.Naruto, Animes.Bleach])
```

but there's also [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```
const anime = new Set(Object.values(Animes));
//    ^^^^^ inferred as Set<Animes>
```

However, this only works if your enum does not contain numerical values.

```
enum What { A, B, C }

new Set(Object.values(What)) // Set { "A", "B", "C", "0", "1", "2" }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAgiCWFgGcoG8BQVtQPImAAV5gBjYKAXigCJ8LizgaAaLHAOQEMAnMAFwD2VWtz5DW7bACEANsC6kAFiJpyFyyQF8MGUJCgB1JV37opsNjijSrOAMJsdGUoJDIzXBEhEEA7lAAysD8ABS4AEYAVmT8AHQAblyyYCihcIgoAJRZANy6ru6C8nGyggDmoV6ZeQVuyMXApRXh0bGJyanIocamOflAA)

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that we can do something like:

```
const animes = new Set(Object.values(Animes))
```

Not sure if this is the best way (more efficient/cleaner) way to do it.

*PS: You can test it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAgiCWFgGcoG8BQVtQPImAAV5gBjYKAXigHJ8LizgaAaLHAOQEMAnMAFwD2VWtz5DW7bACEANsC6kAFiJpyFymhgC%20GDKUEhk-KFwRJU1AgHcoAZWD8AFLgBGAKzL8AdADcusmAoTnCIKACU4QDcegZGgvLesoIA5k5mYcjRQA)*

Answer (score 0):

Given that enums in Typescript are just objects, you could do: `const mySet = new Set(Object.values(Animes));`.

This would be incorrect for numeric enums since they have this weird bidirectional access, in that case just use: `const mySet = new Set(Object.values(MyEnum).filter(x => typeof x === "string"));`

Although this is the simplest way, and due to how these functions are typed, you'd lose the type information